# How can I get string '1,2,3' not '1:3'

Tags: r

There is a string: `s <- '[[1,2,3],[2,5,6]]'`

I use package `jsonlite` to:

```
s <- fromJSON(s) 
s <- split(s, row(s))
```

Then, I get a matrix like this:

```
A matrix: 2 × 3 of type int
1 2 3
2 5 6
```

I hope I can use `as.character(s[1])` to make `s[1]` become `'1,2,3'`. However I get this `'1:3'`

```
as.character(s[1])
'1:3'
```

What should I do?

Comment: This is my code: ```r s <- fromJSON(s)    \n    s <- split(s, row(s))    \n    as.character(s[1])```

Comment: And I get `'1:3'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution:

```r
s <- matrix(1:6,2,3, byrow=T)
s

#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    2    3
#> [2,]    4    5    6

paste(s[1,], collapse=",")

#> [1] "1,2,3"
```

---

Without conversion to `matrix`:

```r
library(stringr)

s <- '[[1,2,3],[2,5,6]]'

str_extract(s, "(?<=^\\[\\[).*(?=\\],)")

#> [1] "1,2,3"
```

Comment: sorry~ it's does not work

Comment: Try the code I have just edited.

Comment: Genius~ It's work~~~ Thank u so much~~~~

Comment: And the second group [2,5,6]] under `stringr`?

Comment: The following extracts both groups, using the logical `or` operator `|`, @Chris: `str_extract_all(s, "(?<=^\\[\\[).*(?=\\],)|(?<=,\\[).*(?=\\]\\]$)") %>% unlist`.

Comment: I was stuck at `unlist(stringr::str_split(s, '\\],\\['))`, which doesn't get one there. Thanks.

Comment: Try this, @Chris: `str_split(s, "\\],\\[") %>% unlist %>% str_remove_all("\\[|\\]")`. Your `str_split` leaves `[[` and `]]` in the two strings, which need to be removed (by `str_remove_all`)

Comment: You can also use your splitting strategy, @Chris, by first removing the left and right square brackets of the boundary of `s` with `trimws`: `trimws(s, whitespace = "\\[{2}|\\]{2}") %>% 
  str_split("\\],\\[") %>% unlist`. (`{2}` means exactly two.)

Comment: Now that was very informative, being able to define what `whitespace` is and preserving the 'cargo' via `{2}`, had no idea that whitespace could be, via `trimws`, any legal characters one wanted to dispense with (With such power comes great ...). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

With `apply`:

```
s <- '[[1,2,3],[2,5,6]]'
s <- jsonlite::fromJSON(s)
s <- apply(s,1,paste,collapse=',')
s[1]
[1] "1,2,3"
```

Comment: cool~ That's a good ideal~